How to predefine values for global variables?
Many projects in Gitlab have pipeline by general template.
Two weeks ago group projects shared on 2 groups.
In WebUI developers have to choose different technological user.
Now it is implemented like this.
In project .gitlab-ci.yml
include:
  - project: 'devops/tools/cicd-templates'
    ref: v1
    file:
      - 'pipelines/.base_pipelines_spark_project_rpm_bricks.yml'

in pipelines/.base_pipelines_spark_project_rpm_bricks.yml
variables: &global-vars
  TECH_USER_DEFAULT: "tech_user_group1"
  TECH_USER:
    value: "tech_user_group1"
    options:
      - 'tech_user_group1'
      - 'tech_user_group2'
      - 'tech_user_group3'
    description: "technological user"

Simple scenario:
section with
variables: &global-vars

move to project .gitlab-ci.yml.
But this scenario has a disadvantage.
Need to more 30 changes over merge request: about more 30 project.
Is it possible to implement it in such a way that the value or options for TECH_USER are filled somehow through a variable?

I'm not sure you can have variables inside the description of another variable.

may be change variables TECH_USER in value: or list options:?

decide to clarification of the question

In GitLab, you can define variables on project or even group level (go on the group -> settings -> CI/CD -> variables).
I don't know your structure, maybe you can edit your question to be more clear.
